# EF Core 6 sproc call requires sproc to include a select 0;

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqldatareader

Summary:

- .NET Core 6.0,  Entity Framework Core 6.0.2.0
- Calling a sproc via EF's `command.ExecuteReader().`
- If I don't include a `select 0;` at the top of my **sproc**, no results are
  returned.

My C# code:

```
using (QuidDbContext context = GetQuidContext())
{
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "dbo.usp_GetBankAccounts";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.NextResult())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int bankAccountId = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
                string name = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My sproc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetBankAccounts
AS
BEGIN
    -- MUST BE HERE:
    select 0;

    select BankAccountID, Name
        from BankAccounts
END
```

This code executes fine, the reader returns each BankAccount record.

However if I remove the `select 0;` line in the **sproc**, no results are returned.

Comment: Remove `if (reader.NextResult())` otherwise you skip the first resultset. This has nothing to do with EF and everything to do with ADO.Net and `IDbDataReader`. The docs say "By default, the data reader is positioned on the first result." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatareader.nextresult?view=net-6.0#system-data-idatareader-nextresult

Comment: So what would cause 'reader.NextResult()' to work when the sproc has that 'select 0;'?

Comment: There are two resultsets, two `select` statements. The reader is positioned on the first one, you are skipping that and moving to the second. If there is no second one then no results. Whereas if you leave out that line then you will get results from the first `select`.

Comment: @Charlieface: Sure enough, that was it.  Removing BOTH the extra 'select' in the sproc, and the 'reader.NextResult()' did the trick.  Thank you!